# Node can't find index.js inside a Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, express, dockerfile

I am trying to use two steps of building an image for my **express.js** app, in order to make it small and efficient as possible.

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
# second step:
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/build /app
COPY --from=build /app/package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=production
EXPOSE 3001
CMD ["node", "/app/build/index.js"]
```

But when I added the second step, node cannot find the file `/app/build/index.js` even though it's there:

[image]

Files in the container that was generated:

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're copying from `/app/build` to `/app` in the final image with

```
COPY --from=build /app/build /app
```

so that's where the file is located.

You can use a relative path to make your CMD simpler and use

```
CMD ["node", "./index.js"]
```

or with an absolute path use

```
CMD ["node", "/app/index.js"]
```